Using XML files with GradeR package in R: Error
I am using GradeR package for autograding of students' tasks, and normally it works fine. The problem emerges if students are asked to read in an XML file using the XML package. In this case, all tests fail. No error message is thrown, but the output looks like this (where master.R is my test assignment file):

The problem DOES NOT emerge if an XML is read from a string, so I assume it has to do with the representation of an XML document in R.
Here is my Grade.R file
library(gradeR)

submissionDir <- "./submissions/"

grades <- calcGrades(submission_dir = submissionDir, your_test_file = "./testthat/test.R")

grades


And here is the test.R file:
library(XML)

t_doc <- xmlTreeParse("my.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
t_rootnode <- xmlRoot(t_doc)

test_that("1", {
  expect_true(class(doc)[1] == class(t_doc)[1])
})

test_that("2", {
  expect_true(class(rootnode)[1] == class(t_rootnode)[1])
})

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance. I am new to autograding.

We need more information for a [mre]. Can you provide a sample, redacted XML? Also, please show the code that The problem DOES NOT emerge if an XML is read from a string.
